# Possibilities of an automorphism on $Z_{20}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

This is a question from the book Contemporary Abstract Algebra, specifically chapter 6 on isomorphisms. The question is:

Suppose that $\phi: Z_{20} \to Z_{20}$ is an automorphism and $\phi(5) = 5$. What are the possibilities of $\phi(x)$?

**Attempt of Solution**

I have made an attempt at solving it. Firstly, we know that an isomorphism carries the identity of the first group to the identity of the second group. Since the identity is $0$, and it is an automorphism, so $\phi(0) = 0$.

Next up, we know that an isomorphism preserves the order of an element. So I made a list of all elements of $Z_{20}$ with the same order. For reference, here's the list (excluding $5$ and $0$):
\begin{align*}
1) & \, \{1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19 \} &\text{ (Order is 20) } \\
2) & \, \{2, 6, 14, 18 \} &\text{ (Order is 10) } \\
3) & \, \{4, 8, 12, 16 \} &\text{ (Order is 5) } \\
4) & \, \{10 \} &\text{ (Order is 2) } \\
5) & \, \{15 \} &\text{ (Order is 4) } \\
\end{align*}
So we can restrict $\phi$ in that if it is an automorphism, it must map $0, 5, 10$ and $15$ to themselves. Also, it can only map the rest of the elements to some element in their set otherwise order will change.

That give $8! \cdot 4! \cdot 4!$ possibilities in total. Is this approach correct, or I'm missing something else?

Comment: $Z_{20}$ is cyclic, thus any automorphism will be completely determined by where it sends a generator.

Comment: Thanks, so you would mean that the first row with elements of order 20 are completely determining the automorphism, since they are the generators. So that means only 8! possibilities?

Comment: No, way less.  There are only 8 automorphisms total.   once you determine where 1 goes, you are done., because $\phi(2)=\phi(1+1)=\phi(1)+\phi(1)$.  Only those that send $\phi(1)$ to something that when you multiply it by 5 mod 20 gives you 5 fits your answer.  For instance,  $\phi(1)=7$ doesn't work because $5\cdot 7=15$ mod 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the comment,  the only possible automorphisms are the ones where $\phi(1)$ are sent to another element of order 20.  Once you have that, everything else is completely determined by the homomorphism property.   So all you have to do is check which of the elements of order 20 that when you multiply by 5, mod 20,  give you 5.  Those are the ones which preserve $\phi(5)=5$

Comment: So that would mean we are left with five possibilities total only, those which map 1 to 1, 5, 9, 13 and 17. Since any other number in the list of generators say $k$ gives $\phi(5) = 5\phi(1) = 5k \mod 20 \ne 5$

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\phi(1)$ so that $\phi(5)=5x$. Then the automorphisms you want are those corresponding to the solutions of the congruence $5x\equiv5\bmod 20$ which are coprime to $20$. The previous congruence is equivalent to
$$
x\equiv1\bmod 4
$$
and thus $x\in\{1,9,13,17\}$

Answer (score 0):

The number of automorphisms from $\mathbb{Z_{n}}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z_{n}}$ is equal to $\phi(n)$ where $\phi$ denotes the Euler's totient function.
You just have to think like this:-
since $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z_{n}}$ , and $f$ is an automorphism, $f(1)$ must also generate $\mathbb{Z_{n}}$ . So you just have to map $1$ to some generator and it would give you the different automorphisms. Now $\mathbb{Z_{n}}$ has $\phi(n)$ generators. So you get your answer. Also the Automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z_{n}}$ will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z^{\times}_{n}}$ or $U_{n}$ where $U_{n}$ or $\mathbb{Z^{\times}_{n}}$ denotes the multiplicative group of units in $\mathbb{Z_{n}}$. $U_{n}$ has order $\phi(n)$ as only the elements which are coprime to $n$ are the units and number of positive integers less than $n$ and coprime to $n$ is precisely the definition of $\phi(n)$.

In particular $\mathbb{Z_{20}}$ has $\phi(20)=\phi(4)\cdot\phi(5)=2\cdot 4 =8$ automorphisms.

Comment: And adding the condition that $\phi(5) = 5$, we further reduce to only 5 automorphisms. So those are the only possibilities. Thanks